# When to combine common functionality? - A public static object w/ initialization

Tags: javascript, coding-style

This is a common occurence when I code...I see some code that looks kind of alike..and I know that it is obviously not good to have redundant functionality in my code.

However , is this absolute?  0 Redundancy?  I have two functions below, which look kind of alike. ViewH.bookmark and ViewH.tweet.

I'm trying to decide if I should pull out the common functionality into a function called ViewH.mark().

**EDIT**

```
var ViewH = {
    MARK: 
    {
        FIELD:      '|',
        ROW:        '||',
        PASS:       '<xx_p>',
        FAIL:       '<xx_f>'
    },
    return_string:  '',
    mark: function(passed_function, embeddedAml)
    {
        var return_string,
            first_split, 
            element_count, 
            second_split;

        return_string = '';
        first_split = embeddedAml.split( ViewH.MARK.ROW );
        for( element_count=0; element_count < first_split.length; element_count++)
        {
            second_split = first_split[element_count].split( ViewH.MARK.FIELD );
            passed_function(second_split);
        }
        return ViewH.return_string;
    },
    bookmark: function ( embeddedAml ) 
    {
        ViewH.return_string='';
        return ViewH.mark(ViewH.bookmark_inner, embeddedAml);
    },
    tweet: function ( embeddedAml ) 
    {
        ViewH.return_string='';
        return ViewH.mark(ViewH.tweet_inner, embeddedAml);
    },
    portfolio: function ( embeddedAml ) 
    {
        ViewH.return_string='';
        return ViewH.mark(ViewH.portfolio_inner, embeddedAml);
    },
    bookmark_inner: function ( second_split )
    {
        ViewH.return_string = ViewH.return_string 
        + '<img name="bo_im" class="c" src="'
        + 'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' 
        + second_split[0] 
        + '" onerror="Arc.BookmarkError(this)"><a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="b" href = "' 
        + second_split[1] 
        + '">' 
        + second_split[2] 
        + '</a>';
    },
    tweet_inner: function ( second_split )
    {
        ViewH.return_string = ViewH.return_string 
        + '<div class="Bb2b"><img class="a" src="' 
        + Constant.PICTURES + second_split[ 0 ] 
        + '.jpg" alt=""/><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0)\">' 
        + second_split[ 1 ]  
        + ' posted ' 
        + ViewH.pretty( second_split[ 2 ],second_split[ 3 ] ) 
        + '</a><br/><p class="c">' 
        + second_split[ 4 ] 
        + '</p></div>';
    },
    portfolio_inner: function ( second_split )
    {
        if( ( second_split[ 1 ] === 'docx' ) || ( second_split[ 1 ] === 'xlsx' ) )
        {   
            ViewH.return_string = ViewH.return_string 
            + '<img name="bo_im" class="c" src="' 
            + Constant.IMAGES + second_split[1] 
            + '.ico"><a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="b" href = "/' 
            + Constant.ROOT 
            + second_split[1] 
            + '/' 
            + second_split[0] 
            + '.' 
            + second_split[1] 
            + '">' 
            + second_split[0] 
            + '.' 
            + second_split[1] 
            + '</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            ViewH.return_string=ViewH.return_string 
            + '<simg name="bo_im" class="c" src="' 
            + Constant.IMAGES 
            + 'generic' 
            + '.ico"><a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="b" href = "' 
            + Constant.TEXT 
            + second_split[0] 
            + '.txt">' 
            + second_split[0] 
            + '.' 
            + second_split[1] 
            + '</a>';
        }
    },
```

Comment: I usually consider code not DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself principle) if more than 2 or 3 lines are repeated in multiple places. These functions look like the are good candidates for combining. Prestaul makes a good point about overengineering though. Not every little chunk needs to be abstracted away.

Comment: I prefer to do it as soon as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question, but there is no answer that will apply to all cases.  It really is going to depend on what your code looks like.  Redundancy is generally to be avoided but it is sometimes worse to over-engineer your code and try to make it fit into a box that it does not really fit into.

In your case you could definitely benefit from taking common code and pulling it into a common method.  It looks like the only difference between your methods is the rendering part and it would be simple to pass a rendering function into your "mark" method.

Your "mark" method would look a bit like this:

```
mark: function(embeddedAml, renderer) {
    var return_string,
        first_split, 
        element_count, 
        second_split;

    return_string = '';
    first_split = embeddedAml.split( ViewH.MARK.ROW );

    for( element_count=0; element_count < first_split.length; element_count++)
    {
        second_split = first_split[element_count].split( ViewH.MARK.FIELD );
        return_string = return_string + renderer(second_split);
    }

    return return_string;
}
```

You would keep your bookmark and tweet methods but they would change as well:

```
bookmark: function (embeddedAml) {
    return this.mark(embeddedAml, function(data) {
        return '<img name="bo_im" class="c" src="' + 
        'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' +
        data[0] + 
        '" onerror="Arc.BookmarkError(this)"><a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="b" href = "' +
        data[1] + '">' + 
        data[2] + '</a>'
    });
}
```

Now your rendering code (the only code that was different) is controlled independently, but the code that overlapped is in a common place and if it changes you only have to update it in one place.

Comment: Thanks that's what I did in the PHP version..and I'll do it here as well.  I thought I might be going oberboard but not quite yet.  I guess if it looks obviously redundant you should refactor it might be a soft guideline.

Comment: And I think the more tired I get...I try and prentend the functions are doing different things..but I just need a lunch break...haha...thanks.

Comment: Heh, we just posted nearly identical code at almost the exact same time.

Comment: lol, totally! This is a relatively strait-forward refactor. Javascript makes this so easy because we can pass functions around so simply. You'll get my +1 :)

Comment: How can I not +1? It's like upvoting myself :)

Comment: Thanks...I just posted my code too...First javascript object (resembles a php collection of public static functions) that I did refactoring in. I like putting all the + signs on their own line as I did in the answer, makes it more readable though I guess I'm breaking some coding stylec convention.  Thanks

Comment: oh...wait..mine works I just ran it but yours and his looks a bit more concise...I'll update in a bit.

Comment: @downvoters_are_sissies, you probably should leave your original code because it was part of the question. Also, I wouldn't use a member property (i.e. ViewH.return_string) because it will cause headaches in the long run. For example, you never clear that variable right now so if you call bookmark twice the second time it will return the first and second call concatenated.

Comment: That's funny b.c. I did that in my PHP code too.  This is what I call a public static model..which is easiest for me to implement b.c. I'm still learning but it has that drawback that you have to initialize your memmber variables..as opposed to if I used say a public non-statc model (were you use new).  I will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, yes.

One deciding factor is whether the code is similar coincidentally, or because it performs a similar task.  If the latter is true, should you change the functionality of one in the future (particularly that part of the functionality which is shared), will you also want to change the functionality in the other?  If so, that makes your decision easy - merge the code where you can.

Even if the code is similar coincidentally, it may still make sense to create a generic library function that cleans up your code.

Comment: Excellent point. At work we refer to this as turducken programming when you force one object to inherit functionality from another simply because they share properties. For example, bird inherits from maxipad because they both have wings.

Comment: Sorry, we call it "turducken" (i.e. a turkey, stuffed with a duck, stuffed with a chicken) because some developers like to shove one object up the ass of another...

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely attempt to combine them. You'll notice that the body of the `for` loop is the only thing that's different between the two. Here's one approach (most of `ViewH` elided):

```
var ViewH = {
    bookmark: function(embeddedAml) {
        return ViewH.combinedFunc(embeddedAml, function(parts) {
            return '<img name="bo_im" class="c" src="' + 
                   'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' +
                   parts[0] + 
                   '" onerror="Arc.BookmarkError(this)"><a target="_blank" name="bookmark_link" class="b" href = "' +
                   parts[1] + '">' + 
                   parts[2] + '</a>';
        });
    },

    combinedFunc: function (embeddedAml, handler) {
        var return_string,
            first_split, 
            element_count, 
            second_split;

        return_string = '';
        first_split = embeddedAml.split(ViewH.MARK.ROW);

        for(element_count=0; element_count < first_split.length; element_count++) {
            second_split = first_split[element_count].split(ViewH.MARK.FIELD);
            return_string = return_string + handler(second_split);
        }

        return return_string;
    },
}
```

You could easily do the same thing for `tweet`. Clearly, you'll want to name the function something better than `combinedFunc`, but you'll need to choose that name based on context.

Comment: +1 for posting nearly identical code to mine and beating me to the punch! When mine posted yours said it was posted 33 seconds ago.